# How to use ctrl+shift+a in SAP?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sap

I've been using SAP(-PM) for a few years now.
And on occasion I have accidentally pressed the keyboard combination control+shift+a.

After which SAP displays all enterable fields with numbers and arrows.
See the image below/link for reference:

[Ctrl+shift+a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmE0Z.png)

I've went on duckduckgo, google and bing to find out what this is.
I've used a number of search terms in a large amount of combination.

The terms used where:

- "SAP",
- "SAP-PM",
- "keyboard",
- "shortcut",
- "control",
- "shift",
- "reference" and
- "list".
  Looking thru accessible help files online for SAP.

However I've found nothing explain this keyboard shortcut and how one should and can use it.

Are there any SAP expert familiar with ctrl+shft+A and its use cases?